# Grouping Unions Together

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to group UNION blocks together? I want to just get a LIMIT for each. Something like

```
SelectQuery1 LIMIT 1
UNION
(SelectQuery2 UNION SelectQuery3) LIMIT 2
```

I want to get the first row in the first query then I want to combine Query2 and Query3 first before getting the first 2 rows.

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

I think so.  Just use subqueries:

```
(SelectQuery1
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(select *
 from (SelectQuery2 UNION
       SelectQuery3
      ) ss
 LIMIT 2
)
```

Note this is a schematic of what to do.  The exact syntax might depend on your query expressions.

Also:

- Use `union all` if appropriate.  `union` removes duplicates, which adds extra processing.
- Usually you want some sort of `order by` when using `limit`.

Comment: Thanks, this syntax works, but for my database, it only returns 2 rows instead of 3. Because the result of SelectQuery1 LIMIT 1 is also in the first 2 rows of the result of SelectQuery2 UNION SelectQuery3. Would you know how to solve that?

Comment: @StackOfQuestions . . . You should ask another question with sample data and the queries that you are actually using.